# Step-chart with cumulative sum based on new intervals given on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, intervals, cumulative-sum

I have two lists: data and given_x_axis

```
data=[[0.05, 3200], [0.1, 2000], [0.12, 1200], [0.13, 2000], [0.21, 1800], [0.25, 2800], [0.27, 1500]]
given_x_axis=[0.05, 0.07, 0.09, 0.11, 0.13, 0.15, 0.17, 0.19, 0.21, 0.23, 0.25, 0.27, 0.29, 0.31, 0.33, 0.35]
```

I want to plot a step chart with cumulative-sum like this,

```
x,y=map(list, zip(*np.cumsum(data, axis=0)))
plt.step(x,y)
```

but using given_x_axis instead as the steps on x axis

I have tried to define a function that recreates a new list of cumulative values based on the given_x_axis

```
def update_x_axis(data, given_x_axis):
 cumulated_values=[]
 value_each_step=0
 for n,x in enumerate(given_x_axis):
  for d in data:
   if d[0]<=x:
    value_each_step=value_each_step+d[1]
  cumulated_values.append(value_each_step)
 return [given_x_axis,cumulated_values]
```

But the new list of cumulative values on y axis does not seem to be correct.
I expect update_x_axis(data, given_x_axis) will return

```
[0.05, 0.07, 0.09, 0.11, 0.13, 0.15, 0.17, 0.19, 0.21, 0.23, 0.25, 0.27, 0.29, 0.31, 0.33, 0.35], 
[3200, 3200, 3200, 5200, 6400, 8400....]]
```

How can I modify my defined function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might misunderstand the question or the desired outcome. What I think you're looking for is this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=[[0.05, 3200], [0.1, 2000], [0.12, 1200], [0.13, 2000], [0.21, 1800], [0.25, 2800], [0.27, 1500]]
given_x_axis=[0.05, 0.07, 0.09, 0.11, 0.13, 0.15, 0.17, 0.19, 0.21, 0.23, 0.25, 0.27, 0.29, 0.31, 0.33, 0.35]

x,y = np.array(data).T
ind = np.searchsorted(x, given_x_axis, side="left")
ind[ind == 0] = 1
res = np.cumsum(y)[ind-1]
```

res is now

```
[ 3200.  3200.  3200.  5200.  6400.  8400.  8400.  8400.  8400. 10200.
 10200. 13000. 14500. 14500. 14500. 14500.]
```

Then plotting,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,np.cumsum(y), marker="o", ls="")
ax.step(given_x_axis, res)

plt.show()
```

[image]